# Why am I getting this unusual error in Android studio while using a service in an activity

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, okhttp

I created a webservice accessing a websocket using okhttps inside an Android app in Android studio but that service is giving me error .
Is there any way I can solve it or other way to access a websocket in Android

I have a similar service in an Android app

```
package com.example.acessibilyapp.service
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.Message
import android.util.Log
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
import okhttp3.WebSocket
import okhttp3.WebSocketListener

object sebSocketListener : WebSocketListener() {

    private val TAG = "Test"

    override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
        super.onOpen(webSocket, response)
        webSocket.send("Android Device Connected")
        Log.d(TAG, "onOpen:")
    }

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket, text)
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: $text")
        println(text)
    }

    override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
        super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason)
        Log.d(TAG, "onClosing: $code $reason")
    }

    override fun onClosed(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
        super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason)
        Log.d(TAG, "onClosed: $code $reason")
    }

    override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ${t.message} $response")
        super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response)
    }
 
}
class WebSocketListener: Service() {
    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

   

    val client = OkHttpClient()

    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()


        val websocketURL = "wss://free.blr2.piesocket.com/v3/1?api_key=AiaSdPmM1Aw231s3Yq4eOq6E2mbjeu55N2tgqqcd&notify_self=1"

    fun starttes() {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(websocketURL)
            .build()

       val  websocket = client.newWebSocket(request, sebSocketListener)
        Thread.sleep(10000)
        websocket.send("Hello")
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // Initialize resources or perform setup tasks
    }
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
      starttes()
        return START_STICKY // Return START_STICKY to ensure service persistence
    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // Perform cleanup tasks and release resources
    }


}
```

When I call this service

```
 val serviceIntent = Intent(this,WebSocketListener )
```

This gives me an error "classifier 'WebSocketListener' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the wrong class that you extended instead of your own class.

```
val serviceIntent = Intent(this, sebSocketListener::class.java)
```

make your `sebSocketListener` class name something like `MySocketListener` so you don't get confused.